# Position text under a div.box using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling trying to replicate [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XaiN.png) using Flexbox.
My result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1nkW.png) for the moment.

Here is the affected code :

```
<div class="box-container">
        <div class="box">
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.box {
  height: 160px;
  width: 155px;
  border: 3px solid #3882f6;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to properly align/position the text under my boxes.

I already tried not nesting the box class with the paragraph but then the text is just hanging next to the box and not under it. I tried to play with margin and width of the container but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.box {
  height: 160px;
  width: auto;
  border: 3px solid #3882f6;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box">
          </div>
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box">
          </div>
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box">
          </div>
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box">
          </div>
          <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

You need to add a parent element for both elements and then just center the text and let the child take 100% of his parent width I believe this solves the issue

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I had to change the width of the wrapper as well for it to fit correctly into my code. Unfortunately, I don't really understand why I need to add a parent element for the box class & paragraph since I already have my box-container. I'm still learning and some things are still weird to me with css.

Comment: The wrapper is required because you're wrapping all the content in one wrapper what you need is a wrapper for each box title so you can manage them the right way since display attribute is applied to parent to manage how the child would be displayed! again don't forget to set the answer as a solution if it is a solution! @digLu0

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```css
 .box-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 25px;
    }

    .box-holder {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      text-align: center;
      height: 240px;
      width: 155px;
    }

    .box {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border: 3px solid #3882f6;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
   
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box-holder">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box-holder">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box-holder">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box-holder">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```